# How do I add java tool in jenkins?

Tags: java, jenkins

I am moving a jenkins build from one server to another jenkins server. The jenkins file is below. It is failing at the line 'java tool' with this error:

**java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'java' found among steps [ansiColor, ... , scm]**

```
node {
    stage 'checkout'
    deleteDir()
    checkout scm

    stage 'build'
    java tool: 'JDK8'

    checkLineEndings()
    maven tool: 'M3', commands: 'clean deploy', arguments: '-P docker'
}
```

I can see under global tools configuration there is a JDK section and I have added JDK8 as an option. I don't see a tool directly called java. Any idea how to fix this issue?

Full error output:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'java' found among steps [ansiColor, archive, bat, build, catchError, checkout, deleteDir, dir, dockerFingerprintFrom, dockerFingerprintRun, echo, emailext, emailextrecipients, envVarsForTool, error, fileExists, getContext, git, input, isUnix, junit, library, libraryResource, load, lock, mail, milestone, nexusPolicyEvaluation, nexusPublisher, node, parallel, powershell, properties, pwd, readFile, readTrusted, resolveScm, retry, script, setGerritReview, sh, sleep, stage, stash, step, svn, throttle, timeout, timestamps, tm, tool, unarchive, unstash, validateDeclarativePipeline, waitForQualityGate, waitUntil, withContext, withCredentials, withDockerContainer, withDockerRegistry, withDockerServer, withEnv, wrap, writeFile, ws] or symbols [all, allOf, always, ant, antFromApache, antOutcome, antPath, antTarget, any, anyOf, apiToken, architecture, archiveArtifacts, artifactManager, associateTag, authorizationMatrix, batchFile, booleanParam, branch, brokenBuildSuspects, brokenTestsSuspects, buildButton, buildDiscarder, buildDiscarders, buildParameter, buildingTag, caseInsensitive, caseSensitive, certificate, changeAbandoned, changeMerged, changeRequest, changeRestored, changelog, changeset, checkoutToSubdirectory, choice, choiceParam, cleanWs, clock, cobertura, coberturaAdapter, command, commentAdded, commentAddedContains, copyArtifactPermission, copyArtifacts, createTag, credentials, cron, crumb, culprits, defaultView, deleteComponents, demand, developers, disableConcurrentBuilds, disableResume, docker, dockerCert, dockerfile, downstream, draftPublished, dumb, durabilityHint, envInject, envVars, environment, equals, expression, file, fileParam, filePath, fingerprint, frameOptions, freeStyle, freeStyleJob, fromScm, fromSource, gerrit, git, gitBranchDiscovery, gitHubBranchDiscovery, gitHubBranchHeadAuthority, gitHubForkDiscovery, gitHubTagDiscovery, gitHubTrustContributors, gitHubTrustEveryone, gitHubTrustNobody, gitHubTrustPermissions, gitTagDiscovery, github, githubPush, gradle, headRegexFilter, headWildcardFilter, hyperlink, hyperlinkToModels, inheriting, inheritingGlobal, installSource, isRestartedRun, istanbulCobertura, istanbulCoberturaAdapter, jacoco, jacocoAdapter, jdk, jdkInstaller, jgit, jgitapache, jnlp, jobBuildDiscarder, jobName, label, lastCompleted, lastDuration, lastFailure, lastGrantedAuthorities, lastStable, lastSuccess, lastSuccessful, lastWithArtifacts, latestSavedBuild, legacy, legacySCM, list, local, location, logRotator, loggedInUsersCanDoAnything, manualApplication, masterBuild, maven, maven3Mojos, mavenErrors, mavenMojos, mavenWarnings, modernSCM, moveComponents, myView, newContainerPerStage, node, nodeProperties, nonInheriting, none, not, overrideIndexTriggers, paneStatus, parallelsAlwaysFailFast, parameters, password, patchsetCreated, pattern, permalink, permanent, pipeline-model, pipelineTriggers, plainText, plugin, pollSCM, preserveStashes, privateStateChanged, projectNamingStrategy, proxy, publishCoverage, queueItemAuthenticator, quietPeriod, rateLimitBuilds, recipients, refUpdated, requestor, resourceRoot, run, runParam, s3CopyArtifact, s3Upload, schedule, scmRetryCount, scriptApproval, scriptApprovalLink, search, security, selectedApplication, shell, simpleBuildDiscarder, skipDefaultCheckout, skipStagesAfterUnstable, slave, sonarToGerrit, sourceFiles, sourceRegexFilter, sourceWildcardFilter, specific, sshPublicKey, sshPublisher, sshPublisherDesc, sshTransfer, sshUserPrivateKey, standard, status, string, stringParam, swapSpace, tag, text, textParam, throttleJobProperty, timezone, tmpSpace, toolLocation, topicChanged, triggeredBy, unsecured, upstream, upstreamDevelopers, userSeed, usernameColonPassword, usernamePassword, veracode, veracodeDynamicAnalysisResubmit, veracodeDynamicAnalysisReview, veracodeDynamicRescan, viewsTabBar, weather, wipStateChanged, withAnt, withSonarQubeEnv, workspace, zfs, zip] or globals [currentBuild, docker, env, params, pipeline, scm]
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:199)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor952.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:163)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:157)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:161)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:165)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:135)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:8)
```

Comment: The command is `jdk`, not `java`, at least on my Jenkins. You might get much better help by not truncating the error message.

Comment: The java tool command is working without issue on a different jenkins server. Now the long story. The builds need to continue on the old jenkins server and need to also be set up on the new jenkins server. I am not allowed to change the source code or the Jenkinsfile mentioned above. Deployments happen from the old server but I need to set up Veracode security scans on the new one. A different team owns the code which contains the Jenkinsfile and they are not agreeing to moving the deployment script to the new server. Older server doesnt support Veracode plugin.

Comment: I am pretty sure it is the other way around: tool "java". Like in the documentation https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#tool-use-a-tool-from-a-predefined-tool-installation

Comment: its working on one jenkins server.